# Package has already posted 50 toasts. Not showing more

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Hello I am working on an app and in which at one point I need to take input from user and store it in database and then fetch that data and put it on different **TextView**. Problem is I did stored the data in database and when i trying to fetch it My app shows a pop up i.e : App is not responding and logcat shows this:
Package has already posted 50 toasts. Not showing more.
I have used 6 database operations before this pullAccStt can this be a problem.

**DatabseAdapotor**

```
public long updateAccSettTable(String loactionName, String hospitalname, String PatientId, String FirstName, String MiddleName, String LastName, String DOB,
                               String Gender, String Weight, String Height, String MobNo, String emailId, String Ethinicity, String patientConcentStatus, String DevicePatientId,
                               String CoSensorId, String DeviceId, String VideoId){
    SQLiteDatabase db= helper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValuesAccSett= new ContentValues();
    contentValuesAccSett.put(DatabaseHelper.PatientId,PatientId);
    contentValuesAccSett.put(DatabaseHelper.LocationName,loactionName);
    contentValuesAccSett.put(DatabaseHelper.HospitalName,hospitalname);

    contentValuesAccSett.put(DatabaseHelper.FirstName,FirstName);
    contentValuesAccSett.put(DatabaseHelper.MiddleName,MiddleName);
    contentValuesAccSett.put(DatabaseHelper.LastName,LastName);
    contentValuesAccSett.put(DatabaseHelper.DateOfBirth,DOB);
    contentValuesAccSett.put(DatabaseHelper.Gender,Gender);
    contentValuesAccSett.put(DatabaseHelper.Weight,Weight);
    contentValuesAccSett.put(DatabaseHelper.Height,Height);
    contentValuesAccSett.put(DatabaseHelper.MobileNo,MobNo);
    contentValuesAccSett.put(DatabaseHelper.EmailId,emailId);
    contentValuesAccSett.put(DatabaseHelper.Ethnicity,Ethinicity);
    contentValuesAccSett.put(DatabaseHelper.P_ConsentStatus,patientConcentStatus);
    contentValuesAccSett.put(DatabaseHelper.DevicePId,DevicePatientId);
    contentValuesAccSett.put(DatabaseHelper.DeviceId,DeviceId);
    contentValuesAccSett.put(DatabaseHelper.CoSensorId,CoSensorId);
    contentValuesAccSett.put(DatabaseHelper.VideoId,VideoId);

    long id1= db.insert(DatabaseHelper.Accoun_setting_Table,null,contentValuesAccSett);
    if (id1<0){
        Message.message(helper.context,"Unsuccessfull");

    }else {
        Message.message(helper.context,"Account setting Updated");

    }

    db.close();
    return id1;


}
public String pullAccSett(){
    String patientId = null;
    Message.message(helper.context,"patient id is: ");
    SQLiteDatabase db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String query="Select * From "+DatabaseHelper.Accoun_setting_Table+" ;";
    Cursor AccCursor=db.rawQuery(query,null);
    Message.message(helper.context,"query "+query);
    while(AccCursor.moveToFirst()) {

        int index1 = AccCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.PatientId);
         patientId=AccCursor.getString(index1);


    }

    AccCursor.close();
    db.close();
    return patientId ;
}
```

**Activity Class calling this**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class AccountSettingFragment extends Fragment {
    FloatingActionButton fabEdit;
    DatabaseAdaptor databaseAdaptor=null;
    TextView PatientId;
    private Context context;


    public AccountSettingFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account_setting, container, false);

        fabEdit=(FloatingActionButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btnFabEdit);
        PatientId=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.patientId);
        context=getActivity();
        databaseAdaptor=new DatabaseAdaptor(context);
       databaseAdaptor.pullAccSett();
        fabEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AccountsSettingEdit.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        return view;
    }


}
```

**Message Class**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by frnds on 3/2/2016.
 */
public class Message {
    public static void message(Context context,String message){
        Toast.makeText(context,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

And when i call this pullAccSett(); my app hangs and goes to not responding.
and log cat shows message:
Package has already posted 50 toasts. Not showing more.
What is the reason behind this.

Comment: Remove the toast code and check once.

Comment: I have done that but still its the same

Comment: you are using toast within the while loop, remove it and if want information use Log.i("",""); to print information in logcat

Comment: I removed toast but still it hangs when that particular tab is called.
log cat now says: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 17.  Wait queue head age: 5931.6ms.)

Comment: what do you want to do in pullAccSett() method ?

Comment: i want it to fetch data which i have stored in updateAccSettTable.

Comment: I got Package has already queued 5 toasts. Not showing more.  How did you get 50? I wish!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **while** loop i thinks will runs for infinite time. because every time it will be true and you have no break statement.
so change your code like this.

```
try {
    if (AccCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while (AccCursor.moveToNext()) {
        //code for fetch data from cursor
        }
    }

    AccCursor.close();
}catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Getdata", e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some enhancement for the code above. If cursor is in position -1, AccCursor.moveToNext will move it to position 0, so you can do better something like:

```
try {
    while(AccCursor.moveToNext()) {
        //Execute code
    }
    AccCursor.close();
}catch(final Exception lException) {
    Log.e("Getdata", "Exception looping Cursor: " + lException.getMessage());
}
```